# solving ode and plotting solution vs time

Tags: differential-equations

I'm currently trying to solve this system of two ode's and can't seem to be able to solve them. I am new to coding, so I don't know where I could have done a mistake. I'm attaching the code which I thought would give a answer, but have gotten an error which I don't understand. What it is in reference too. Please, if you could guide me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Also, if it is not to much to ask for any hints on plotting x and y vs time. Thank you for you help.

```
equation1 := {x'[t] == 
    1/(1 + (1/25) (y[t] - (2 y[t])/(1 + sqrt[1 + 1600 y[t]]))^2) - 
     0.1 x[t], 
   y'[t] == 
    0.5 x[t] - (((20 y[t])/(1 + sqrt[1 + 1600 y[t]]) + 
         0.03 y[t])/(0.05 + y[t])) - 0.1 y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0};
DSolve[equation1, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

During evaluation, DSolve::ivar: 5 is not a valid variable. >>

```
(* DSolve[{0 == -0.1 5[t] + 1/(
    1 + 1/25 (15[t] - (2 15[t])/(1 + sqrt[1 + 1600 15[t]]))^2), 
  0 == 0.5 5[t] - 0.1 15[t] - (
    0.03 15[t] + (20 15[t])/(1 + sqrt[1 + 1600 15[t]]))/(
    0.05 + 15[t]), 5[0] == 0, 15[0] == 0}, {5[t], 15[t]}, t] *)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

First, sqrt->Sqrt. Then, because you use real numbers (like 0.1, etc...) I will assume that you don't need an analytic solution. You want just plot.
Then solution is easy.

```
equation1 = {x'[t] == 
   1/(1 + (1/25) (y[t] - (2 y[t])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 1600 y[t]]))^2) - 
    0.1 x[t], 
  y'[t] == 0.5 x[
      t] - (((20 y[t])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 1600 y[t]]) + 0.03 y[t])/(0.05 + 
        y[t])) - 0.1 y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}; sol = 
 NDSolve[equation1, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and plot

```
Plot[{Tooltip[x[t], "x[t]"], Tooltip[y[t], "y[t]"]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 
  0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, Evaluated -> True]
```

As it was already suggested you have to read about Mma base syntax.

Comment: this still gives an error though

Comment: Which version do you use? At least in 10.01 it is ok, I just checked once more by copying /pasting both cells.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt` should be capitalized, if it is meant to be the standard Mathematica function, `Sqrt`.  Also, there is no need to use `SetDelayed`.  With these changes, no errors are produced, but the code does not produce an answer in a reasonable amount of time.  It seems likely that `DSolve` cannot solve these equations.  So, try

```
{sx, sy} = NDSolveValue[equation1, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which quickly produces an answer.

```
Plot[{sx[t], sy[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much i do have a question tough as time is increased the graph just seems to flat line and apparently it is not supposed

Comment: This is the correct solution, I believe.  Moreover, setting the derivatives to zero yields a steady-state solution (using `Solve`) of `{2.26164, 9.40081}`, which agrees well with the late time solution of the differential equations.  By the way, to use this site effectively, you really should read the two-minute tour that I mentioned in a comment yesterday.